# Cannot change anchor text font size when it is inside a div

Tags: html, css

It is really strange that I cannot change the font size of the link:

```css
.linkunderthepicture a {
  width: 99%;
  font-size: 18;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkunderthepicture"><a href="http://google.com">Click</a></div>
```

Comment: font-size can't be unitless: you need to specify an absolute or relative unit

Comment: your're missing `"px"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the unit of measurement to the `font-size`. Add `px`, `em`, or `%` to the end of 18.

```css
.linkunderthepicture a {
  width: 99%;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkunderthepicture"><a href="http://google.com">Click</a></div>
```